# How correct delete folder in IIS server

Tags: powershell, iis

I wrote functional in powershell which delete virtual folder in IIS, delete physical path, unzip archive to folder, and create virtual path in IIS with old name. The problem in step 2. Script try delete files and folder.

```
...
get-childitem ($pathToIIs + "*") -recurse | remove-item -Force -recurse
...
```

Powershell throws error:

> Cannot remove item C:\inetpub\test\css: The directory is not empty. + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (css:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], I
>    OException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell
>    .Commands.RemoveItemCommand
>    + PSComputerName        : test.cloudapp.net

If understand correct, to stop and start IIS it's bad idea. So how fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *MUST* stop IIS to be able to remove files locked by IIS:

```powershell
...
iisreset /stop
get-childitem ($pathToIIs + "*") -recurse | remove-item -Force -recurse
iisreset /start
...
```

Stopping IIS will obviously and temporarily prevent your server from serving web pages.